# Maximum operating temperatures of different lead acid batteries

Tags: lead-acid

What are the (generally) safe maximum operating temperatures of various lead acid batteries such as wet cells, sealed lead acid, glass mat?

I'm looking for a battery that can withstand around 60 degrees C at a low discharge rate (recharge would be at room temperature). If lead acid batteries are not appropriate, what would be a better alternative?

operating-temperature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look long and hard at Lithium Ferro Phosphate (LiFePO4) batteries.

Serveral times the cost of lead acid insom cases. Lowest whole of life cost in most cases.

Much on web.

[From battery university](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/types_of_lithium_ion) :

[image]

Here are a few CLAIMS.

[Ping batteries](http://www.pingbattery.com/servlet/StoreFront) Shanghai -20 - +70 C
 Making LiFePO4 batteries since 2007.

[YESA batteries](http://www.yesa.com.hk/pages.asp?id=19) Hong kong. -20 - +75

[Liberty elecric bikes](http://www.iloveebikes.com/batteries.html) PA, USA.  -20 ~ +70

Answer (score 2):

There are industrial batteries that fall into your requirements.  You would need to read the specifications to know if a particular model is recommended in that range.

I have used the Hawker Genesis under extreme circumstances, but not those that you describe.  However, the [specifications (pdf)](http://www.masterinstruments.com.au/Data%20Sheets/Hawker%20Cyclon/Hawker%20Genesis%20databook.pdf) indicate that GnnEPX are rated for -40 - +60 degrees C for storage, discharge and charge.

This is just one example, you would want to review the specifications of the particular model(s) of interest.

**Edit:**  The general answer is that most lead acid batteries will NOT be rated for 60 C.